# RPL Border Router running in Contiki Cooja

Tags: iot, contiki, cooja

I am working on a project in Contiki-NG using one udp-server and several udp-clients. Up to this moment, I've been using only these firmwares, **emulated in Contiki Cooja as Sky Motes**, but **now I need to add a RPL Border Router**, which will be the DAG root, in order to perform pings with tunslip6 tool.

However, I can't seem to compile this tool as explained in the [tutorials available in github](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Tutorial:-RPL-border-router)...  The ReadMe file in the examples folder says: "It supports two main modes of operation:
embedded and native."

Does this mean I can't use tunslip6 with RPL-Border-Router from Contiki-NG Cooja?
I remember that I was able to perform that when using the Contiki-3.x version of this example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For connections with the Cooja simulator, you need to make the target `connect-router-cooja` instead of the target `connect-router`. In the first case, the border router connection is made via a TCP socket. In the second case, it is made by opening a serial device file.

The Cooja and border router setup is descibed in a separate Wiki page:  https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Cooja:-simulating-a-border-router